# % sign not working inside tabular

Tags: tables, input-encodings

What is wrong with this table?

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Firms  & Revenues & Shares & Shares in  Percentage & HHI  \\
Anheusar Busch & 50400092.4 & 0.490059433 & 49.01% & 2401 \\ 
MillerCoors & 38038521.08 & 0.369863133 & 36.99% & 1369 \\ 
Heineken & 14406243.85 & 0.140077435 & 14.01% & 196 \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I need a percent sign though

Comment: then use `\%` instead of `%` alone

Comment: it works by replacing % with \%. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: ... and use \\ instead of \ at the end of the rows

Comment: @SAM 'Firms & Revenues & Shares & Shares in Percentage & HHI \' should be 'Firms & Revenues & Shares & Shares in Percentage & HHI \\' etc.

Comment: @SAM OK, in this moment I can reload and it's OK

Comment: @abel: Please consider also to use the `siunitx` package for the display of the numbers and the `%` character